# Dropdown custom Text in dropdown after selecting a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to have different text in dropdown after selecting a value? for example I have this dropdown:

```
<select name="selectsupplier">
    <option value="sup0001">sup0001 - Supplier 1</option>
    <option value="sup0002">sup0002 - Supplier 2</option>
</select>
```

If I select the first option, the usual dropdown text will be "sup0001 - Supplier 1". Is it possible to change it to only the Supplier's code (sup0001) without the name?

Instead of this:

[image]

the selected text should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a plugin / framework component (e.x. bootstrap dropdown) to post render the <select> tag?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#phoneCallingCode').change(function() {
    $("#ShowNumber").val("+" + $("#phoneCallingCode option:selected").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="phoneCallingCode" id="phoneCallingCode" class="input">
  <option value="sup0001">sup0001 - Supplier 1</option>
  <option value="sup0002">sup0002 - Supplier 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="ShowNumber"/>
```

i hope it will help you, your concept something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I believe you want to change the option text on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = $("select[name=selectsupplier]").children();
  options.each(function(i, item) {
    var optionText = $(item).text().replace(/ -.*/g, '');
    $(item).text(optionText);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectsupplier">
    <option value="sup0001">sup0001 - Supplier 1</option>
    <option value="sup0002">sup0002 - Supplier 2</option>
</select>
```